# STMCUBEIDE - H7 series force use of SMLAL (Signed Multiply with Accumulate (32 × 32 + 64), 64-bit result) instruction

Tags: arm, stm32

STM32CUBEIDE compiler produces inefficient code.

```
int16_t     OscPhase[NumOsc];
int32_t     OscInc[NumOsc];
int32_t     OscVol[NumOsc];
int32_t     Sine[65536];

int64_t     OscTotal;


and then in main() :

        OscTotal = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < NumOsc; i++)
        {
            OscPhase[i] = OscPhase[i] + OscInc[i];
            OscTotal = OscTotal + Sine[OscPhase[i]]  * OscVol[i];
        }
```

I was expecting the H7 to use the SMLAL instruction for the final multiply and accumulate but instead it performs a MUL.W which only gives a 32 bit result and then uses an ADD.W and ADC.W to add these 32 bits into the final 64 bit result.

Any suggestions on how to force it to use the correct code ?

Comment: Try `OscTotal = OscTotal + (int64_t)Sine[OscPhase[i]]  * (int64_t)OscVol[i];` or `OscTotal = OscTotal + ((int64_t)Sine[OscPhase[i]]  * OscVol[i]);`  I have a distant memory of having to cast all the operands to 64bit types to get the keil compiler to spit out `SMLAL`

Comment: What compiler is it you're using?

Comment: It's STM's new STM32CubeIDE which appears to use an out of date GCC.   You are right - I eventually got to the same answer that casting all as 64bits is the only way to use SMLAL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having done some experimenting with [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/B0rKhF), the code

```
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t mac (int64_t  sum, int32_t x, int32_t y) {
   return sum + ((int64_t)x*y);
}
```

emits

```
mac:
        smlal   r0, r1, r3, r2
        bx      lr
```

when compiled with ARM GCC 7.2.1 and the flags `-march=armv7e-m -mcpu=cortex-m7 -O3`, with `-O1` or no optimization level specified it doesn't generate the `SMLAL` instruction.

Without the cast it doesn't generate `SMLAL` as it's performing a 32 x 32 => 32 multiplication, whereas `SMLAL` does 32 x 32 => 64.

The `mac` function does appear to get inlined if used in a loop, so there's no extra branching.

Comment: Thanks.  I found with -O3, the compiler unrolled the code which isn't necessary on an M7.  -O1 as you say dumps code that won't accumulate correctly.   I found -O2 to be the most reliable method.  I'm about to go and try using your MAC declaration and see if it does inline it, as it will avoid me having to check the assembly code every time I change a line :-)

Comment: Edit : yes it did inline it.  Next problem is it does a 64bit load and then store each side of it, rather than keeping OscTotal in a register pair until the end.  Working on that one.  Thanks for your help